# osmconvert cannot convert pbf file with -b option

Tags: openstreetmap, convert

I've downloaded the latest UA.osm.pbf file from

```
  http://data.gis-lab.info/osm_dump/dump/latest/UA.osm.pbf
```

I've installed osmconvert `0.8.5` to my `Ubuntu 16.04` 
`osmconvert` successfully opens and creates statistic for `UA.osm.pbf` file

```
osmconvert UA.osm.pbf --out-statistics
-----------------------------------------------------------------
timestamp min: 2007-02-21T08:17:13Z
timestamp max: 2016-07-28T23:31:48Z
lon min: 19.1582119
lon max: 56.0369675
lat min: 41.6472555
lat max: 56.9060947
nodes: 44162664
ways: 5058105
relations: 110626
node id min: 487747
node id max: 4326298295
way id min: 4306002
way id max: 434671917
relation id min: 2865
relation id max: 6445175
keyval pairs max: 309
keyval pairs max object: relation 60189
noderefs max: 2000
noderefs max object: way 87717954
relrefs max: 3630
relrefs max object: relation 2094111
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Finished! Calculation time: 8s.
```

Also it can successfully convert pbf ==> 05m

But if I try to crop it by `-b` option I get file 167 bytes length

```
osmconvert UA.osm.pbf -b=47.45,32.94,49.19,36.94 --out-pbf -o=UA.osm_01.pbf

algot@algot-16:~/mapbuild/osmand-pbf$ ls -la
-rw------- 1 algot algot       167 UA.osm_01.pbf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 algot algot 380945644 UA.osm.pbf
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've found what is a problem.
boundary parameters order is different than osmosis have so I needed to change order of longitude/latitude and all works ok